# $.prompt()- pop up appears multiple times on a single hit

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a simple user login panel, when the username password is incorrect pop up appears with a message. But the problem is, often(not always) for incorrect or empty fields, the pop up appears twice. I am aware it can have simple solution, but I have been trying for a long time to solve it. So. any piece of valid suggestion would be a great help.

My javascript code looks like the following:

```
$("#password").keypress(function(e)
    {
        if (e.which == 13)
        {
            performLogin();
        }
    });

function performLogin(){
        var uName = $("#userName").val();
        var uPass = $("#password").val();
        var licenseType = $("#licenseType").val();

        $.post('./qServer',{
            type:'login',
            userName:uName,
            password:uPass,
            licenseType:licenseType
        }, function(data){
            someText = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
            if(someText=='1'){
                window.location.reload();
            }
            else if(someText=='2')
            {
                $.prompt("Enter Required Field(s) Value");
            }
            else if(someText=='0')
            {
                $.prompt("Database Err: User Name or Password not valid"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='3')
            {
                $.prompt("Database Err: Invalid user"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='-1')
            {
                $.prompt("Failed to connect with Database"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='-2')
            {
                $.prompt("Syntem is unavailable please wait.."); 
            }
            else if(someText=='-3')
            {
                $.prompt("System is ready to undeployment. If you want to resume services without further deployment please restart you server"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='52e')
            {
                $.prompt("Active Directory Err: invalid credentials"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='525')
            {
                $.prompt("Active Directory Err: user not found"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='530')
            {
                $.prompt("Active Directory Err: not permitted to logon at this time"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='531')
            {
                $.prompt("Active Directory Err: not permitted to logon at this workstation"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='532')
            {
                $.prompt("Active Directory Err: password expired (remember to check the user set in osuser.xml also)"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='533')
            {
                $.prompt("Active Directory Err: account disabled"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='701')
            {
                $.prompt("Active Directory Err: account expired"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='773')
            {
                $.prompt("Active Directory Err: user must reset password"); 
            }
            else if(someText=='775')
            {
                $.prompt("Active Directory Err: user account locked"); 
            }
            else 
            {
                $.prompt("Active Directory Err: not authenticated user!"); 
            }

        });
    }
```

**NOTE**
I have checked and found out when ever Enter key is pressed after password is given, the problem occurs.

Comment: can you check whether `performLogin` is called multiple times

Comment: Just my 2 cents, Can you use `switch` instead of multiple `else if` conditions?

Comment: problem will only occure if performLogin is called multiple time.

Comment: ArunPJohny and KrupeshKotecha, yes it has been call twice, once when 'enter' is pressed after password and when Sign In button is clicked.  Only when enter is pressed the pop us is shown twice.  Sri Harsha, switch did help !

Comment: I have used e.stopImmediatePropagation(); to stop calling `performLogin` multiple times. and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I myself could solve the problem just adding a line as following:

```
$("#password").keypress(function(e)
    {
        if (e.which == 13)
        {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            performLogin();

        }
    });
```

`e.stopImmediatePropagation()` stops multiple firing of `performLogin()`.